# I can't get access to my hdd

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted

So I've got this hdd, it stopped working a few months ago. Now I'm trying to see it with gparted,I'm trying to unmount all the partitions but with one of them I get this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYldb.jpg

What can I do? Also the partitions I can't unmount are marked with a key, I don't know if the hdd is dead or something. Thanks for reading, I hope someone can help me c:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAnz4.jpg    [Gparted]

Comment: You appear to be trying to unmount the root filesystem of your working OS, rather than that of the HDD that you are trying to examine

Comment: Boot from Live Ubuntu USB and use gparted from that.  Make sure you are working on right drive before doing anything.  Do not count on the sdx labels, know which drive/s partitions you need to keep.